# Adding a particular file from a folder to .gitignore

Tags: reactjs, github, directory, filepath, gitignore

```
src/
.gitignore
```

My directory looks like this. There is a keys.js file inside src folder. How do i add keys.js to .gitignore ? I have tried various paths but none of it is working

Comment: Please add the paths you've tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your file is already being tracked by `git`, first try to remove it from the cache :

`git rm --cached <file-path>`

In your case it would be `git rm --cached src/keys.js`

Git will delete this file just from the cache ,to be precise from `git repository`. The file still remains in your working area for you to work upon.

You will need to commit this change.

And then modify your `.gitignore` file with below pattern, assuming your src is directly sitting under the root directory as is the case for most react apps, at least the ones created with `create-react-app` (for future refrence keep this [doc](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore#:%7E:text=Prepending%20a%20slash%20matches%20files%20only%20in%20the%20repository%20root.) handy)

`/src/keys.js`

Comment: you say "first try to remove it from the cache" - is there a scenario where this might fail? I mean the git rm --cached command, is there a case where it might fail to remove the specified file from the cache?

Comment: If the file is not tracked by git, the command should result in failure.